# Admin Categories Page Infinite 302 Redirection after migrating the data from 1.9.3.6

Tags: magento2, redirect

For some reason when I go to **Catalog** >> **Categories** page it goes into infinite 302 redirection loop. All other pages work fine. I noticed the issue after migrating the data from Magento v1.9.6.3.

Since there is no any error log or message I am not able to pinpoint the exact cause.

I have already tried enabling and disabling SSL, specifying cookie domain name, clearing browser cookies and cache, specifying session path, trying out with a different browser, re-indexing the data, etc.

If you could point me in the right direction or help me fixing the issue it would mean a lot.

**Update:**
Now I am getting `Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found` error. I think the categories that were transferred from version 1.9.3.6 has been assigned to the non-existing store. Since I cannot access Categories in the admin is there any other way to rectify the issue?

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found
#0 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(167): Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository->getById('5')
#1 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractCollection.php(85): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore('5')
#2 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Model/ResourceModel/Block/Collection.php(44): Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractCollection->performAfterLoad('cms_block_store', 'block_id')
#3 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(588): Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection->_afterLoad()
#4 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(559): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#5 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Source/Page.php(40): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#6 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php(338): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page->getAllOptions()
#7 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider->getAttributesMeta(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type))
#8 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callParent('getAttributesMe...', Array)
#9 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type))
#10 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/Interceptor.php(65): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getAttributesMe...', Array, Array)
#11 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php(262): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->getAttributesMeta(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Type))
#12 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider->prepareMeta(Array)
#13 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callParent('prepareMeta', Array)
#14 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Array)
#15 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('prepareMeta', Array, Array)
#16 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php(198): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->prepareMeta(Array)
#17 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider->getMeta()
#18 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(302): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider\Interceptor->getMeta()
#19 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(208): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata('category_form', Array, true)
#20 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(135): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('category_form', NULL, Array)
#21 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(97): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'category_form', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#22 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(80): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#23 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(344): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#24 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#25 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#26 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#27 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#28 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#29 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#30 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu')
#31 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu')
#32 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#33 /home/dev38/public_html/app/code/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit.php(73): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog...')
#34 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(24): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit->execute()
#35 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->execute()
#36 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#39 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Plazathemes/Override/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Edit/Interceptor.php(39): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#43 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Plazathemes\Override\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#46 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/dev38/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#48 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /home/dev38/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#50 /home/dev38/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#51 {main}
```

[image: Redirection Error]

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 6):

Check your **root_category_id** in table **store_group**

That solved the problem for me!

[image]

Comment: To add on, check the category id from catalog_category_entity table

Comment: You helped me much!

Comment: Perfect,  Record modified due to migration and got that error. Your answer has saved day ! thanks

Answer (score 2):

FYI this is happening for possibly upto 2 reasons.

1.) in the DB in the core_config_data search for this path catalog/category/root_id and make sure the correct ID is set for the related store / root ID in your DB

2.) in the stores -> all stores you should make sure you have the correct category set.. in my case.. for example it was set to a root catalog ID of 88.. however my overall goal was to force it to be ID 2.. so i couldn't simple just change the current category 88 to 2.. instead i had to make a new row in the DB and force as 2.. then in admin i changed the category for the store to my new id = 2 and then i could delete the root category id 88.. this worked.. However when i tried to change 88 to 2.. the redirect your describing occurs.. and no way around it.. even if i had the id set i mention in #1.. still occured.. i even rebuild indexes etc no luck

Answer (score 1):

I found that after the migration from M1, I just needed to go to

> Stores > All Stores
>
> Click on the websites Store View
>
> Select a Root Category
>
> Save